Fortify SCA flag on Input Hidden Fields
Fortify SCA does not like this in form submissions when trying to validate a textfield for duplicate values for example on the front-end:
<input type="hidden" name="checkduplicate" id="checkduplicate" value="yes">
This is because it is expect that attackers will study and decode all uses of hidden fields in the application. Fortify suggested to treat hidden fields as untrusted input, and to not store information in hidden fields if the information should not be cached along with the rest of the page.
As such, is there an alternative solution I can implement?
I do not want to use the following due to the following reasons:

Setting 'validation' values in session attributes is not feasible as javascripts cannot have access to it.

Client-side validation relying on server-side is not possible as repeated validation calls between client and server will just slow the web app down.

AJAX have been suggested as well. However, this method also needs to communicate with server, which again slows down the user experience.


